# How do you instantiate a NSCollectionViewItem from main Storyboard for use in a collectionView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I have a Storyboard that contains a controller with a NSCollectionView. The Storyboard also contains a NSCollectionViewItem with outlets connected to NSCollectionViewItem subclass, FeedItem.

[image]

How do you use the the "cell" or "scene" from the Storyboard (not a separate nib file) in the itemForRepresentedObjectAt method?

This is what I have so far..

```
  class FeedsController : NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
    let collectionViewItem = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "FeedItem")) as! FeedItem

    collectionViewItem.urlLabel.stringValue = "http://www.seanbehan.com"
    collectionViewItem.entriesLabel.stringValue = "15 Entries"
    collectionViewItem.updatedLabel.stringValue = "Last Update: June 1st at 3:15PM"

    return collectionViewItem
  }
}

class FeedItem : NSCollectionViewItem {
  @IBOutlet weak var urlLabel: NSTextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var updatedLabel: NSTextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var entriesLabel: NSTextField!
}
```

It is a MacOS Cocoa app using Swift 4.1

Answer (score 2):

## Storyboard Option

If you want to include the `NSCollectionViewItem` in the same storyboard as your `NSCollectionView`…

- Using the **Library** (plus symbol, upper right, cmd-shift-L), drag a `NSCollectionViewItem` onto (and empty area of) the canvas.
- Using the **Document Outline** (left of canvas, menu: Editor->Document Outline), select the "Collection View Item" in the "Collection View Item Scene".
- Using the **Identity Inspector** (right of canvas, cmd-option-4) assign the "Storyboard ID" to "MyCustomItem".
- *Optional: for reasonably complex items or for maintainability reasons, you may want to change the "Class" to a custom subclass.*
- It's non-intuitive, but `NSCollectionViewItem` is a subclass of `NSViewController`. In your implementation of `NSCollectionViewDataSource` implement…

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        guard let item = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "MyCustomItem") as? NSCollectionViewItem else {
            return NSCollectionViewItem()
        }
        // …
        return item
    }
```

note: subclasses will want to change `as?` downcast class to their subclass

There is no need to use any of the `register` methods for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to instantiate `NSCollectionViewItem` from storyboard is [itemProtorype](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/1528285-itemprototype) which is **deprecated** at 10.14

If you still using an older SDK, you could do so

```
let itemIdentifier = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "CollectionViewItemIdentifier")

if let item = NSStoryboard.main?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: itemIdentifier) as? NSCollectionViewItem {
    collectionView.itemPrototype = item
}
```

But I highly recommend to use *.xib* and methods described by Apple documentation:

- Class [register(_:forItemWithIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/1528268-register) or Nib [register(_:forItemWithIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/1528174-register)
- DataSource method [collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewdatasource/1524271-collectionview)

Long story shorts you have to use .xib file for your NSCollectionViewItem

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewdatasource/1524271-collectionview) are always worth glancing at:

> You do this by calling the `makeItem(withIdentifier:for:)` method of the collection view to retrieve an empty item object of the appropriate type.

And as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/1528240-makeitem) further explain, to do that you will need to have registered a nib or a class with the collection view.

Comment: Clearly neither the nib nor the class is going to hand you the view item that can be instantiated in the storyboard, so Don't Do That.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I read the docs. I initially had this.. code `collectionView.register(FeedItem.self, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("FeedItem"))` and `let collectionViewItem = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("FeedItem"), for: indexPath) as! FeedItem`
` but it throws an exception ` `-[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: FeedItem in bundle (null).`

Comment: So shouldn't the question be about why that code didn't work?

Comment: I'm not using a nib file. I want to grab the view from the storyboard w/out using a nib file.

Comment: To me it seems odd that you can't use a storyboard for the UI of a collection view item and would be required to use a nib.

Comment: And I'm saying you can't. Unlike iOS collection view cells, there are no collection view item prototypes in the storyboard on macOS. So you can't get a reusable collection view item that way.

Comment: Of course it's odd. But this is what happens when iOS is slowly read back onto macOS. It's like the weird way view controllers or CALayer-backed views has gotten folded in.